# How to host two websites on AWS on Windows and Apache but only one site works

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache, virtualization

I have two sites we'll call Site1.com and Site2.com.
I recently converted my VPS with another host to an image and imported the image into AWS. On the VPS, I was able to serve up both sites. Under AWS, whichever URL is accessed first, the second site will display the content and the URL will change to the first accessed site.

The setup is unique in that it is Windows running an apache web server (very old application). No changes to the conf files have been made since the conversion so I can only assume that it's something unique with the AWS setup.

Why is it doing this and more importantly how can I fix this so that I don't have to spin up a second instance.

Comment: How is your Apache setup?  If it assumes 2 distinct IP addresses (one for each domain) and you now only have one on AWS, this could lead to issues.  There is something going on between the IP configuration and the `<VirtualHost>` directives in Apache.  Not enough details in the question to really help further.

Comment: @Nic3500 I wanted to keep the question a little vague in an effort to not influence the help (need fresh eyes on the issue). On the original VPS, there was only one IP. On the EC2 instance, there is also only one IP which was setup through an elastic IP. There are no SSL to contend with so it should be a pretty simple setup.

Comment: @Nic3500 when you say there is something going on between the IP configuration and the <virtualhost>, are you referring to the httpd.conf and the vhosts.conf files?

Comment: You should put more details.  Ex. site1.com resolve to 1.1.1.1, site2.com resolves to 1.1.1.1 as well.  So you should have 1.1.1.1 as a public address which links to your server.  You should have 2 `<VirtualHost>` sections, one for each site.  There might be some redirections in there as well.  Post your `<VirtualHost>` configuration, put `LogLevel debug` and do some tests.   Post these as well, they might indicate what is going on.

Comment: I'm not aware of loglevel debug. I'll give it a whirl (that's a fun word) and report back. Thanks @Nic3500.

Comment: The debug lots will appear in the error_log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue is with the instance type. When I bumped it up to medium (from small), the issue resolved itself. Go figure.